# JS: Can someone explain me this regex and is it possible to write without regex exp?

Tags: javascript

I do not have experience with regex, I found this in code and I am trying to understand it. This is regexp: `(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);`
And context in which is used is next:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
let matches = queryString.match(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);
let count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
```

Also, I am interested is this possible to write in a different way, not to use regexp?

Comment: Start with https://regex101.com/r/uB4vt7/1

Comment: There are online tools which ca explain regexp and helps a lot, eg https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's checking how many query strings are in the url.

`/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]` says any letter or digit between an `=` and another letter or digit should match.

The `gi` part means it is global case insensitive.

- `g` = global, match all instances of the pattern in a string, not just one
- `i` = case-insensitive (so, for example, /a/i will match the string "a" or "A".

```js
const urlQueryString = 'https://test.com/page?name=ferret&color=purple'
let matches = urlQueryString.match(/[a-z\d]+=[a-z\d]+/gi);
let count = matches ? matches.length : 0;

console.log(count) // --> 2 name=ferret color=purple
```

There is a tool available [here](https://regex101.com/r/WLSf16/1) allowing you to test the regex.

Answer (score 0):

This code will count amount of query parameters present in string. However, you can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class for counting entries in query strings.

```js
// URL: https://example.com/?query1=value&query2=value
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// This row will map iterator into array
// [ ['query1', 'value'], ['query2', 'value'] ]
const entriesArray = [...searchParams.entries()];

// 2
console.log(entriesArray.length);
```